# How to Disable Button if Form String Input is Empty React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, chakra-ui

I'm trying to disable a submit button on a form if the input text is empty, or if it's greater than 150 characters. For some reason it's working if the input is greater than 150 characters but not when it's empty and I'm not sure why. I've tried everything and I'm still stuck. I'm not sure if it's because I'm using Chakra UI or it's something else. Thank you in advance.

This is what I have:

```
const AddNewPost = () => {
const { isOpen, onOpen, onClose } = useDisclosure();
const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
const [isSaving, setSaving] = useState(false);

const handleSubmit = async () => {
    const date = new Date();

    await db.collection("posts").add({
        title,
        createdAt: date.toUTCString(),
        updatedAt: date.toUTCString(),
    });

    onClose();
    setTitle("");
};

return (
    <>
    <Button onClick={onOpen} colorScheme="blue">
        Add new post
    </Button>

    <Modal onClose={onClose} isOpen={isOpen} isCentered>
        <ModalOverlay>
            <ModalContent>
                <ModalHeader>Add new post</ModalHeader>
                <ModalCloseButton />
                <ModalBody>
                    <FormControl id="post-title">
                        <FormLabel>Post title</FormLabel>
                        <Textarea
                        type="post-title"
                        value={title}
                        onChange={(e) => 
                            {
                                if (e.target.value.length > 150) {
                                    window.alert("Message must not exceed 150 characters")
                                } else {
                                    setTitle(e.target.value)}
                                }
                                 
                            }
                            
                        />
                    </FormControl>
                </ModalBody>
                <ModalFooter>
                    <HStack spacing={4}>
                        <Button onClick={onClose}>Close</Button>
                        <Button
                        onClick={handleSubmit}
                        colorScheme="blue"
                        disabled={
                            !title || title.length > 150}
                        isLoading={isSaving}
                    >
                        Submit
                    </Button>
                    </HStack>
                </ModalFooter>
            </ModalContent>
        </ModalOverlay>
    </Modal>  
    </>
);

}; export default AddNewPost;
```

Comment: why not checking the title length as well? title.length === 0?

Comment: @EDev unfortunately that isn't working either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Chakra UI Button props](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/button/props) documentation the button has no `disabled` prop.

The correct propname is `isDisabled`

```js
isDisabled={title === "" || title.length > 150}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I tried that too and it still isn't working

Comment: omg i cant believe i missed this thank you so much you're a lifesaver